# Aligning Label in Frame Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am new to Python and even newer to Tkinter.

I am currently practicing how to use Frames and Labels and

the problem I am encountering is, when I put Labels on a frame with some buttons next to each label,

the alignment is not good to look at.

Here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.namelist = ["Mark","Anna","Jason","Lenna","Leo","Zucharich","Robinson","AReallyLongNameThatMightExist"]
        self.canvas = Canvas(width=1200,height=700)
        self.canvas.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH)
    def Friends(self):        
        controlframe = Frame(self.canvas)
        controlframe.place(x=600,y=300)
        #Frame for showing names of friends
        for x in self.namelist:
            frame = Frame(controlframe)
            frame.pack()
            Name = Label(frame,text="%s "%x).pack(side=LEFT)
            chatButton = Button(frame,text="Chat").pack(side=LEFT)
            delButton = Button(frame,text="Delete").pack(side=LEFT)
            setcloseButton = Button(frame,text="Set Close").pack(side=LEFT)
            setgroupButton = Button(frame,text="Set Group").pack(side=LEFT)
        mainloop()

GUI = GUI()
GUI.Friends()
```

What should I do so that the alignment of the Label(=name) and the button is equal to the other ones so that they will form a shape of a rectangle and not some zigzag?

Comment: The short answer is use grid instead of pack. The grid geometry manager is a bit harder to use but much more powerful than pack.

Comment: But isn't `grid` not that flexible when it comes to geometry?
I saw that `grid` uses `row` and `column` which is quite difficult for me. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost always better in Tk to use the grid geometry manager. It is much more flexible once you come to understand how it works. Converting your example to use grid solves your problem as shown below but you should experiment with it a bit. Try removing the 'sticky="W"' from the label for instance and see that the centering of the widgets within the row or column can be controlled. To get your frame responding to resizes sensibly you should investigate the columnconfigure and rowconfigure options for the grid geometry management as well.

```
from Tkinter import *

class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.namelist = ["Mark","Anna","Jason","Lenna",
                         "Leo","Zucharich","Robinson",
                         "AReallyLongNameThatMightExist"]
        self.canvas = Canvas(width=1200,height=700)
        self.canvas.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH)

    def Friends(self):
        frame = Frame(self.canvas)
        frame.place(x=600,y=300)
        #Frame for showing names of friends
        row = 0
        for x in self.namelist:
            label = Label(frame,text="%s "%x)
            chatButton = Button(frame,text="Chat")
            delButton = Button(frame,text="Delete")
            setcloseButton = Button(frame,text="Set Close")
            setgroupButton = Button(frame,text="Set Group")
            label.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky="W")
            chatButton.grid(row=row, column=1)
            delButton.grid(row=row, column=2)
            setcloseButton.grid(row=row, column=3)
            setgroupButton.grid(row=row, column=4)
            row = row + 1
        mainloop()

GUI = GUI()
GUI.Friends()
```

Comment: Wow, the power of `grid`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you do run into long names - you can restrict the displayed length. But that is done on the label widget. eg: `label = Label(frame,text="%s "%x, width=10, anchor="w")` will cause the labels to be restricted to 10 chars and anchored on the left side so you see the first part of the name.

Comment: Do you know how to put limit on the show of Labels in such that if the labels exceed 10 labels, then a scrollbar will appear?

Comment: You can do that by using a ScrolledFrame. See http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/389955-tkinter-scrollbar-grid-managed-frame for some help on that. Frames themselves don't support scrolling.